# Web Database - tx.executeSql callback not running every time

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, web-sql

I have an HTML5 website built using jQuery Mobile.

On my index.htm page I have an ahref. When I click on that link I run a function which does a tx.executeSql and the callback method is run which then navigates to the new page.

The works fine the first time.

If I navigate to more pages and then come back to the index.htm page, the functions are run when the link is clicked, however the callback on the tx.executeSql isn't ever run.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.   I have used all different mechanisms for calling the functions from javascript to jquery, but it makes no difference.

To be clear - the first function called is setFeaturedRecruiter() - you can see the code below.   The second time I come back here the "renderResults" callback function isn't run.

```
// when we click on the actual featured recruiter link we copy from this table to the featured recruiter table to overwrite its contents
function setFeaturedRecruiter() {
    alert('setFeaturedRecruiter()');
    retrieveActualFeaturedRecruiter();
    return true;
}

function retrieveActualFeaturedRecruiter() {
    alert('retrieveActualFeaturedRecruiter()');
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
    alert('select * from featuredRecruiterActual...');
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM featuredRecruiterActual', [], renderResults, pnetOnError);
    });
}

pnetOnError = function (tx, e) {
    alert('Something unexpected happened: ' + e.message);
}

function renderResults(tx, rs) {
    alert('renderResults()');
    var idNo;
    var name;
    var logo;
    var totalAds;
    for (var i = 0; i < rs.rows.length; i++) {
    r = rs.rows.item(i);
    idNo = r.idNo * 1;
    name = r.name;
    logo = r.logo;
    totalAds = r.totalAds;
    }

    writeToFeaturedRecruiter(idNo, name, logo, totalAds);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've worked around this problem by disabling ajax when navigating between pages. This was done by adding to the ahref tag: data-ajax="false". This caused the page to load correctly and overcomes the problem.